# V8Context not created when passing "about:blank" to ChromiumWebBrowser's constructor

Tags: c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

The steps to reproduce this are very simple. Just download the latest version of CefSharp.WinForms (57.0.0) with nuget, then add a button and this code to a form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ChromiumWebBrowser WebBrowser;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("about:blank");
        panel1.Controls.Add(WebBrowser);
        WebBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void testButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(WebBrowser.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then run the application, wait a few seconds to make sure "about:blank" has loaded and press the `testButton`. The message box will show `False`. In fact, if I attempt to use `EvaluateScriptAsync` I will get an exception telling me the context has not been created.

One way to solve this is to call `ShowDevTools`, which seems to somehow force a context to be created. Another solution is to navigate to a non local page such as Google. In this case, even if I go back to "about:blank" I'll be able to run scripts. I tried using a custom scheme registered with `CefSettings.RegisterScheme`, but navigating to my custom page still does not create a context (I tried passing "about:blank" to the constructor and then navigating to my custom scheme and the other way around too and none worked).

So, is it possible to have CefSharp create a context without having to navigate to a non-local page or to show DevTools?

Comment: Your page needs to have JavaScript on it to create a context.

Comment: @amaitland why so strict requirements? As i'm remember contexts can be created on-demand (at least obtaining v8 context from frame should lead to this).

Comment: @amaitland BTW feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Adding a script to my custom scheme page solved it.

Comment: @fddima It's there to provide users with a clear boundary for when they can execute JavaScript. The number of questions I see where people are trying to execute JavaScript before the page has even begun loading or during a navigation/reload is endless. You are correct, it's possible to execute JavaScript and create a context, you just have to wait for the page to load sufficiently, this is still possible in CefSharp, the restrictions I've added are only imposed in the helper extension methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to use the following functions:

```
WebBrowser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(string code);

WebBrowser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(string code);
```

This bypasses the regular check for `V8Context`.

More information from CefSharp, found [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/30ee538ce0e0d1d33ed838665758ec2061165224/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L971):

> For frames that do not contain JavaScript then no V8Context will be created. Executing a script once the frame has loaded it's possible to create a V8Context.
>
> You can use `browser.GetMainFrame().ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script)` or `browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync` to bypass these checks.