# Unable to read CefSharp Chromium console message

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a WinForm application that using cefsharp web browser. From what I learnt about cefsharp, the events `MouseDown`, `Click` cannot trigger in WinForm. So I decided to use javascript to send a message to the console, and trigger `ChromiumWebBrowser.ConsoleMessage` event instead. But that did not work well. Did I mess up the javascript code or execute the code wrongly?

Here are the codes, please noted that `UI.cs` is a Form object. A panel object `pn_Browser` already created in the design view. What I tried to do is, click any element and send "success" to the console. Then the `Background` show the received message if the message in console.log is "success".

**Background.cs**

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
public Background() 
{
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com");
    browser.ConsoleMessage += browser_ConsoleMessage;
    browser.FrameLoadEnd += browser_FrameLoadEnd;
}

public void browser_ConsoleMessage(object sender, ConsoleMessageEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.Message == "success") 
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Received message.");
    }
}

public void browser_FrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e) 
{
    Chromium.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.addEventListener(\"click\", function() {alert('Detect a click.');});");
}
```

**UI.cs**

```
public UI() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Background background = new Background();
    pn_Browser.Controls.Add(background.browser);

    background.browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += browser_JavascriptMessageReceived;

    background.browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(
        "function test() {console.log(\"success\")}" +
        "document.addEventListener(\"click\", test);"
    );
}

delegate void JavascriptReceivedCallback(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e);

private void browser_JavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e) 
{
    if (InvokeRequired) 
    {
        JavascriptReceivedCallback callback = new JavascriptReceivedCallback(Browser_JavascriptMessageReceived);
        Invoke(callback, new object[] { sender, e };
    }
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JavaScript looks like it has a mistake. Your attempting to access your test function before it's been declared,  change the order.

Comment: For JavaScript events I suggest https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent

Comment: Hi @amaitland. Thanks for the reply. I've updated the code but still no luck to solve it. Did I miss setting properties?

Comment: You haven't called CefSharp.PostMessage so JavascriptMessageReceived will never be called.  Add a breakpoint to your ConsoleMessage event handler and see if it's triggered. No special settings are required.

Comment: document.addEventListener usage is also likely incorrect,  I don't believe the document object has a click event,  use mouseup or mousedown instead.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document#event_handlers for reference

Comment: Okay. In this case at `UI.cs`, I should call PostMessage like `$CefSharp.PostMessage({function} {eventListener})` at `ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded`?

Comment: Your original question is about ConsoleMessage not working,  fix your JavaScript,  confirm that works, post post your own answer. If you have a question about PostMessage then ask a new question.

Comment: @amaitland sorry for the late update and thanks for the helping. I finally found the true reason why unable to read. It is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747832/v8context-not-created-when-passing-aboutblank-to-chromiumwebbrowsers-constru and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51636092/cefsharp-error-browser-not-yet-initialized-when-execute-executescriptasync. Thank you for your time.